# Open an Oracle .dmp file from excel 2007

Tags: oracle, excel, excel-2007, dmp

I have an oracle .dmp file which I would like to open from excel 2007. How do I use the 'get external data' feature to do so? Is it possible in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, no.

Assuming the `.dmp file` was produced by the Oracle export utility, that is a proprietary, undocumented binary file.  Only Oracle's import utility would be able to read it.  The import utility can dump the DDL statements for the structure(s) in the dump file to a flat file but if you want to look at the data, you'd need to import that data into an Oracle database.

Comment: Some tools exist (didn't find free ones, but) : http://www.convert-in.com/ord2xls.htm